# GPS tracking another device without internet connection

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I know there are a lot of threads about GPS in Android, but I did not find an answer for this. Is it possible to track the position of another android device, and send some information between this two devices only with GPS (with no Internet connection)?

Answer (score 3):

GPS is a one-way information channel from satellites to devices which want to know their own position. There is absolutely no way you can send information via GPS.

If you are looking for direct communication between android devices, your best options are [Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) and [Wi-Fi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).

Comment: Ive just have an idea that i can recieve position of my device with gps and send it with internet ,that can be posibble ?

Comment: yes @JánSrniček, you acquire the location via GPS and send it via any of the several communication methods available for android devices (wifi, 3G, bluetooth, wifi-direct, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's simply impossible. No internet connection = no communication.